# Determine the validity of feature importance for a regression

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, r-caret

My goal is to determine the "Feature Importance" in a regression task (i.e. I want to know which feature influences the target variable the most).

Let´s assume I use a multiple regression.

There are different methods to determine the feature importance: Model dependent measures like (standardized) Betacoefficients, Shapley Value Regression and model independent measures like Permutation Importance.

All methods are made for specific situations (i.e. Shapely Value Regression is made for situations in which the predictors are highly correlated, where permutation importance takes interaction effects into account). However, these assumptions are a result of theoretical considerations and simulated data sets, which means that the validity (the difference between the "true" values and the measured values on the actual data) is dependent on the structure of the actual data set.

Is there a way In R to determine the measured difference between the measured and the "true" values of the feature importance?

I can use cross-validation the measure the difference between the predicted and the actual values. As an example, I use the Hitters data set.

```
library(ISLR)
library(caret)


fit = train(Salary~., data = Hitters, method = "lm", trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 3), na.action = na.omit)
```

I can take a look at the tuning results and the difference between true and predicted values. Here I have an RMSE of ~ 334.

```
fit$results

  intercept     RMSE Rsquared      MAE   RMSESD RsquaredSD    MAESD
1      TRUE 333.9667 0.468769 239.7604 75.13388  0.1987425 40.58342
```

But what´s about the Betacoefficients. I can look at them but can't figure out how they differ from the actual betas on the test set.

```
coef(fit$finalModel)
 (Intercept)        AtBat         Hits        HmRun         Runs          RBI        Walks        Years       CAtBat        CHits       CHmRun 
 163.1035878   -1.9798729    7.5007675    4.3308829   -2.3762100   -1.0449620    6.2312863   -3.4890543   -0.1713405    0.1339910   -0.1728611 
       CRuns         CRBI       CWalks      LeagueN    DivisionW      PutOuts      Assists       Errors   NewLeagueN 
   1.4543049    0.8077088   -0.8115709   62.5994230 -116.8492456    0.2818925    0.3710692   -3.3607605  -24.7623251
```

Is there a way in R to get this information (also for other measures like the Permutation Importance or Shapely Value Regression)?

Comment: Feature importance may be calculated from other methods, maybe more intuitive : Odd ratio or Partial correlations. Moreover, it is difficult to analyse the betas from k folds cross validation. As the model is trained several times and the outputs `fit$results` is the average resulting from the CV runs. I do not know how to extract each of them from the `caret` package. However, if you want to see how feature importance varies, you can performed you model on different subsets and calculate Odd ratios/Partial correlations for each subset. Hope this helps

Comment: I think this question might be better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/. Also I removed the mlr tag since this question does not contain any mlr code.

Comment: @ pat-s: I add mlr because there might be a solution in this package but not in caret. Yes, the question is a hybrid between a theoretical and a coding question. I wasn´t sure which of both is the better place.

Comment: @ tom: The Betacoefficients are an example of a measure of feature importance. Actually, they are usually not as precise as Permutation Importance. I read different blog posts and papers on this topic and about the pros and cons of each measure. However, nowhere I found a method to determine the precision of each measure for an actual data set. I though caret/mlr may have a solution for this problem. Caret offers the option `savePredictions = 'final'` where I can see the actual vs. the predicted values.